# Add Standard/Custom fields to Visual Force/Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, dynamic-visualforce

Problem:

Click on your name in salesforce -> My Settings -> Personal -> Advanced User Details

Here there are some standard check-box fields (i.e. Marketing User, Salesforce user, Force.com flow user, offline user etc...) and my own custom check-box fields. I want to add these custom as well as standard field (Check-boxes) to one of my visual force page/apex.

First, Is it possible?
Second, If possible, suggest how can I achieve this.

Comment: Pretty basic functionality. Suggest you goto developer.force.com and read up on the platform

Comment: ... and work through training material such as the [Visualforce Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_vf/workbook_vf.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add new fields by going into >Customize>Users>Fields. 
Adding them to a Visualforce page should be a simple matter of adding an input tag to the tag with that field tagged to it.